# What would be the best katakana for this book title?

Tags: katakana

I'm trying to write about a Spanish book in Japanese. I'm a beginner at Japanese so have patience. The English title is 'Chronicle of a Death Foretold'.

クロニックル・オ・エー・デス・フォートールド

I'm not sure on the word for death.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> クロニクル・オブ・ア・デス・フォートールド

is the best katakana if you're only transcribing English.

But, in Japanese,

> 予告{よこく}された殺人{さつじん}の記録{きろく}

is its official title, so I'd use that.

Comment: Even if the book title is in English? I thought for a title in English (Like for instance: Death Note　デスノート) it is written in Katakana. I'm just a beginner too, so honestly curious.